# Grails GORM question

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes:

```
class A {
 String Name
 ...
}

class B {
 A request
 B response
 ...
}
```

How can I get a list of unique As that are present as "requests" in B ? I tried

```
def g = A.findAll("from A as e, B as r where e=r.request")
```

But I have problems extracting the resulting objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
B.executeQuery( "select distinct b.request from B b" );
```